# Using an if & statement

Tags: r

I am trying to do an if & statment in R:

I want to do something like this:

```
if (x > 1) & (y = "Yes) {"replace")
```

I've also tried

```
if (x > 1) && (y = "Yes") {"replace")
```

Which I read on StackOverflow.

How do I convert the excel formula

```
=IF(AND(cell > 1, cell = "Yes"),100,0)
```

Comment: Try `df$New <- ifelse(df$cell > 1 & df$cell == "Yes",100,0) `

Comment: @Duck why do we sometimes provide answers in comments?

Comment: Because it is an easy solution that could be found on other questions :)

Comment: The solutions on the other questions do not work. And your answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Does it work?

```
if (x > 1 & y == "Yes") {"replace"}
```